# Convert bytes io to an array with shape and specific description

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a bytes IO that I read from a file.

I have description as follow

```
[('Time', '<u4'), ('Acc1', '<f4'), ('Acc2', '<f4'), ('Acc3', '<f4'), ('Acc4', '<f4'), ('Weg1', '<f4'), ('Weg2', '<f4'), ('DMS1', '<f4'), ('DMS2', '<f4'), ('DMS3', '<f4'), ('DMS4', '<f4')]
```

and I have source bytes from a file. I constructed the array with a shape correctly.

but I get that error

```
NotImplementedError: memoryview: unsupported format T{L:Time:f:Acc1:f:Acc2:f:Acc3:f:Acc4:f:Weg1:f:Weg2:f:DMS1:f:DMS2:f:DMS3:f:DMS4:}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzZAS.png)

I have posted a picture where you can see what's going on

Some excerpt code

```
 # create the array
    _array = recarray(shape, descr)
    _array.data[:] = fd.getvalue()[offset:offset + nbytes]
```

fd is a bytesIO object.

```
descr = format_parser(formats,namelist, aligned, byteorder)._descr
```